# I need help bulkifying this code.... I keep getting either DML error count or SOQL error count

Tags: apex, trigger, code-coverage, before-trigger

I'm writing my first APEX trigger and test class, However I'm:

1 this code does EXACTLY as I want it to do when an individual changes "Account Status"... but I know it won't work for mass uploads

If anyone can advise I'd greatly appreciate it.

Below is the trigger

```
    trigger CountNumberAccounts on Account ( before update, before insert) {

    list<Account> OnDeckAcc = [SELECT Id, account_status__c, ownerId FROM Account Where Account_status__c = 'On Deck' AND ownerId = :UserInfo.getuserId() ];
    list<Account> InprogAcc = [SELECT Id, account_status__c, ownerId FROM Account Where Account_status__c = 'In Progress' AND ownerId = :UserInfo.getuserId() ];
    list<Account> HldOvrAcc = [SELECT Id, account_status__c, ownerId FROM Account Where Account_status__c = 'Hold Over' AND ownerId = :UserInfo.getuserId() ];


    for(Account a : trigger.new ){
        if( UserInfo.getUserId() == a.ownerId && a.account_status__c == 'On Deck') {
            OndeckAcc.add(a);
            if(ondeckacc.size()>40) {
            a.adderror('You are limited to only 40 On Deck Accounts');
            }
        }
        else if(  UserInfo.getUserId() == a.ownerId && a.account_status__c == 'In Progress') {
            InprogAcc.add(a);      
            if (InprogAcc.size()>150) {
            a.addError('Sucks for you!! You are limited to only 150 In Progress Accounts');
            }
        }
        else if( UserInfo.getuserID() == a.ownerID && a.account_status__c == 'Hold Over') {
            HldOvrAcc.add(a);
            if(HldOvrAcc.size()>40){
            a.adderror('You are limited to only 40 Hold Over Accounts');
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

and this is my test class

```
@istest
private class TestCountNumberAccounts {
    static testMethod void validateTestCountNumberAccounts() {
        Try{
            FOR(Integer i = 1; i<=50; i++){
                Account acc = new Account();
                acc.name = 'SFDC' + i;
                acc.Account_Status__c = 'On Deck';
                acc.Type = 'None';
                acc.OwnerId = '005j000000CCbzW';
            insert acc;
            system.debug('How many quereies');
        }
        } catch( DmlException e) {           
        }
        Try{
            FOR(Integer i = 1; i<=164; i++){
                Account onhold = new Account();
                onhold.name = 'SFDC' + i;
                onhold.Account_Status__c = 'In Progress';
                onhold.Type = 'None';
                onhold.OwnerId = '005j000000CCbzW';
                insert onhold;            
        }
        } catch( DmlException f) {
        }
        Try{
            FOR(Integer i = 1; i<=75; i++){
                Account ondeck = new Account();
                ondeck.name = 'SFDC' + i;
                ondeck.Account_Status__c = 'Hold Over';
                ondeck.type = 'None';
                ondeck.OwnerId = '005j000000CCbzW';
            insert ondeck;
        }
        } catch( DmlException g) {
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: at least that test will almost never fail......ahem...Throw an uncaught error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplified your trigger a bit and it should now handle bulk records. Comment on code within code block

```
trigger CountNumberAccounts on Account ( before update, before insert) {
    Set<String> includeStatus = New Set<String>{'On Deck', 'In Progress', 'Hold Over'};
    Id userId = userInfo.getUserId(); //Since we call it a lot cache it. Not sure if it makes a significant difference though 

    Map<String,Integer> cnt = New Map<String,Integer>(); //Store the counts

    for(String s : includeStatus) cnt.put(s,0); //Default Values
    //The NOT IN filter is so we do not include the trigger records in the count since we will be incrementing them below
    for(AggregateResult ar : [Select Account_Status__c, Count(Id) num From Account Where Account_Status__c In :includeStatus AND OwnerId = :userId AND Id NOT IN :trigger.new Group By Account_Status__c]){
        cnt.put(
                (String)ar.get('Account_Status__c'),
                (Integer)ar.get('num') 
        );
    }

    for (Account a : trigger.new) {
        if(a.OwnerId != userId) continue; //if Not OwnerId match then continue

        //Lets increment based on the status here 
        cnt.put(
                a.Account_Status__c,
                cnt.containsKey(a.Account_Status__c) ? (cnt.get(a.Account_Status__c) + 1) : 1
        );

        //Now check sizes
        if (a.account_status__c == 'On Deck') {
            if (cnt.get('On Deck') > 40) {
                a.adderror('You are limited to only 40 On Deck Accounts');
            }
        } else if (a.account_status__c == 'In Progress') {
            if (cnt.get('In Progress') > 150) {
                a.addError('Sucks for you!! You are limited to only 150 In Progress Accounts');
            }
        } else if (a.account_status__c == 'Hold Over') {
            if (cnt.get('Hold Over') > 40) {
                a.adderror('You are limited to only 40 Hold Over Accounts');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Agreed the trigger could be coded better, but does this change address the question of "I keep getting either DML error count or SOQL error count"?

Comment: Thanks for this Eric, however, when I test this using the same above test class, I get an error " Attempt to de-reference a null object"

Comment: @B-Roge - If you tell me where I can fix it for ya? Basic debugging

Comment: @Eric it doesn't throw an error in the debug files when I run the test class... but when I go to physically update an account in my sandbox then i see the "de-reference a null object"  from what I can calculate it's coming from somewhere in  `  //Lets increment based on the status here 
        cnt.put(
                a.AccountStatus__c,
                cnt.containsKey(a.Account_Status_c) ? (cnt.get(a.Account_Status__c) + 1) : 1
        );
`

Comment: Check the debug logs when you try to update an account. It will tell you then. It will also tell you the line number etc...I don't trust any test method unless I see it as most don't actually test anything. Also, It cannot come from the line you say as we check from the key being present and above that we set the values to 0 by default.. It is most likely something else....

Comment: @B-Roge - Any update? Would love to get this fixed for you...

Comment: @eric bear with me while i lear the basic debugging skills. but it looks like it's coming from here `for(AggregateResult ar : [Select Account_Status__c, Count(Id) num From Account Where Account_Status__c In :includeStatus AND OwnerId = :userId Group By Account_Status__c]){
        cnt.put(
            (String)ar.get('Account_Status__c'),
            (Integer)cnt.get('num')
        );
        system.debug('aggregate results debug');`

Comment: @B-Roge - Nothing there would give DNO. Can you post the debug log in your question (can remove it later) and we can see whats going on....

Comment: @B-Roge - I made some edits. Just put it in my dev org (needed a few changes first) and it works fine in initial testing. Grab the updated code and see if it works for you. If it does not then post the debug logs

Comment: @eric - this was the debug log I got back `10:56:22:067 USER_DEBUG [14]|DEBUG|aggregate problemAggregateResult:{Account_Status__c=On Deck, num=39}string{Hold Over=0, In Progress=0, On Deck=null}`

Comment: @B-Roge - See updated code. I had `cnt.get('num')` and it should be `ar.get('num')` - Apologies and thanks for the debug

Comment: @B-Roge - YW and Thank you for sticking with me. Coding blindly in the middle of the night without debugging can use some hiccups. Glad it worked out in the end though!

Answer (score 0):

While the trigger probably isn't perfect (particularly for the update case), the bigger problem is probably in the test. Best to separate the 3 cases out into separate methods and the inserts need to be done in bulk to avoid hitting the DML governor limit for the 150 case:

```
private static Account[] newAccounts(Integer n, String status) {
    Account[] access = new Account[] {};
    for (Integer i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.name = 'SFDC' + i;
        acc.Account_Status__c = status;
        acc.Type = 'None';
        // acc.OwnerId = '005j000000CCbzW';
        accs.add(acc);
    }
    return access;
}

static testMethod void onDeck() {
    insert newAccounts(35, 'On Deck');
    try {
        insert newAccounts(10, 'On Deck');
    } catch (DmlException e) {
        // Assert no errors on first 5 but errors on last 5
    }
 }

 static testMethod void inProgress() {
    insert newAccounts(145, 'In Progress');
    try {
        insert newAccounts(10, 'In Progress');
    } catch (DmlException e) {
        // Assert no errors on first 5 but errors on last 5
    }
 }

 ...
```

See the [Exception Class and Built-In Exceptions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm) documentation for the `DmlException` methods that allow you to check the number of failed rows etc.

Hard coding Id values (such as the Account OwnerId) is best avoided. As tests are isolated from existing data in an org you could just not set that value and allow it to default to the User that is running the tests.

Comment: Thanks Keith!  This works and passes but my code coverage is still 0% after running this test class.  Do you know why that might be?

Comment: @B-Roge Are you looking at code coverage like this https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_dev_console_tests_coverage.htm&language=en&type=0?

Comment: yes, I can't even get a percentage of coverage to show up.  There is  no color on the code whatsoever. I only get the option of "Code Coverage: None"